# Error: QGIS standalone script in crontab

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to automate QGIS (2.18.4) standalone scripts in ubuntu using crontab.
My scripts execute well when running from command, but fail if I put in crontab.

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.gui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

In crontab, it fails at `app = QApplication([])`. Crontab gives error as

> : cannot connect to X server

How to make my QGIS standalone script run in crontab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is actually not related to this community, you should ask in [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) to get better answers.

To run a GUI command with a cronjob, you'll have to tell cron what display the program should use:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

`:0` is the default Display. If you like the program to run on other display, please change the number accordingly (e.g. :1, :2, etc).

Your cron command will look like this:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && python /path/to/your/command.py
```